# How to vertically align text in a @Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: html, css, razor

How can I vertically center text in a @Html.TextAreaFor?

Here is the html

```
<table class="width100percent padding0Margin0">
            <tr class="height35">
                <td class="width150">
                    Description
                </td>
                <td class="textValignMiddle">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Job.Description, new { @class = "width646 height25", @placeholder = "Enter " + @Model.GetNameJob + " description" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I have tried to following css but nothing is how I need it

```
.textBottom{vertical-align: text-bottom;}
.textTop{vertical-align:text-top;}
.textVerticalAlignTop{vertical-align:top;}
.textBaseLine{vertical-align:baseline; }
.textValignBottom{vertical-align:bottom;}
.textValignMiddle {vertical-align: middle;}
```

Is the only way to do this add padding-top then downsize the size of the textbox?
[image: What the issue is]

Comment: You can't center text vertically in a text area. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Guffa The project code is the one I want to change and the project code is what I want to replicate with the textArea

Comment: @WillNZ http://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/1794/ May helps you

Comment: @Sam1604 thanks but this didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Please Following this css...

```
.textValignMiddle 
{
vertical-align:middle;
display: table-cell;
float: none;
}
```

Comment: Is this to be applied to the <td> or the textAreaFor?

Comment: All Ready applied class { class="textValignMiddle" } in your code so this css applied..